# Move resource to different domain based on subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Several companies are sharing resources (wiki, forum, shops...), now they like to use ONE server certificate for this.

The url looks as following:

```
company1.domain1.com or www.company1.domain1.com
company2.domain2.com or www.company2.domain2.com 
company3.domain3.com or www.company3.domain3.com
```

New pointing to the same `newdomain.com/company1` on the hosting.

What I want to achieve at the end is:

```
newdomain.com/company1
newdomain.com/company2
newdomain.com/company3
```

In the browser when somebody type `www.company2.domain2.com` in the URL you should see `http://newdomain.com/company2` (without `www`)

I need two examples. One is exactly this thing I described. Second is the same thing, but at the end in URL I want see `https://newdomain.com/company2` (without `www`)

Answer (score 0):

In the htaccess file in your `domain1.com`, `domain2.com`, `domain3.com`, etc, document root, add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^.]+)\.[^.]+\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/%2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect `http://www.mycompany.somedomain.com/path/to/file.txt` to `http://newdomain.com/mycompany/path/to/file.txt`